# What is the cause of OutOfMemoryException in .NET on the Windows service under a heavy load?

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, lucene.net, out-of-memory

I have a Windows service that is doing some maintenance work. Recently we added a job that attempts to precalculate some search result by using [Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene), and since then it started throwing OutOfMemory (OOM) exceptions.

Some details which I got from [WinDbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) and [SOS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
0:034> !analyzeoom
Managed OOM occured after GC #176014 (Requested to allocate 2621440 bytes)
Reason: Low on memory during GC
Detail: SOH: Failed to reserve memory (16777216 bytes)
```

!dumpheap -stat command result (the last ones)

```
65fe4944    81900     34614564 System.Byte[]
65fe2938    76014     35904328 System.Int32[]
65f96064       74     39988372 System.Int64[]
65fdf9ac  3208118    150302932 System.String
00265090      363    247694656      Free
Total 9035539 objects
```

So there is free memory, but it gets fragmented and all portions are less that 16 MB (default allocated segment).
Array of bytes, ints and int64 are hold by Lucene Cache. Cache is activated because of a query that uses sort. The Lucene cache implementation is based on WeakReferenceHashMap and thus should be cleaned by the garbage collector in case of memory starvation.

Heapstat command

```
0:034> !heapstat
Heap             Gen0         Gen1         Gen2          LOH
Heap0         1643476      2689484    526084512    196389976

Free space:                                                 Percentage
Heap0              12           12    170262384     77432248SOH: 32% LOH: 39%
```

The exception dump from a log file looks like:

```
Quartz.Core.ErrorLogger - Job (DEFAULT.precalculate-similar-index threw an exception.
Quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at Lucene.Net.Search.FieldCacheImpl.LongCache.CreateValue(IndexReader reader, Entry entryKey) in C:\Dev\Lucene.Net_2_9_2\src\Lucene.Net\Search\FieldCacheImpl.cs:line 685
   at Lucene.Net.Search.FieldCacheImpl.Cache.Get(IndexReader reader, Entry key) in C:\Dev\Lucene.Net_2_9_2\src\Lucene.Net\Search\FieldCacheImpl.cs:line 240
   at Lucene.Net.Search.FieldCacheImpl.GetLongs(IndexReader reader, String field, LongParser parser) in C:\Dev\Lucene.Net_2_9_2\src\Lucene.Net\Search\FieldCacheImpl.cs:line 639
   at Lucene.Net.Search.FieldCacheImpl.LongCache.CreateValue(IndexReader reader, Entry entryKey) in C:\Dev\Lucene.Net_2_9_2\src\Lucene.Net\Search\FieldCacheImpl.cs:line 667
   at Lucene.Net.Search.FieldCacheImpl.Cache.Get(IndexReader reader, Entry key) in C:\Dev\Lucene.Net_2_9_2\src\Lucene.Net\Search\FieldCacheImpl.cs:line 240
   at Lucene.Net.Search.FieldCacheImpl.GetLongs(IndexReader reader, String field, LongParser parser) in C:\Dev\Lucene.Net_2_9_2\src\Lucene.Net\Search\FieldCacheImpl.cs:line 639
   at Lucene.Net.Search.FieldComparator.LongComparator.SetNextReader(IndexReader reader, Int32 docBase) in C:\Dev\Lucene.Net_2_9_2\src\Lucene.Net\Search\FieldComparator.cs:line 481
```

The only idea I got till know is that the exception is caused by memory fragmentation. Unfortunately there is no answer to the question why memory is not compressed.

We don't pin any objects and it seems that Lucene doesn't either, although !gcroot command returns for some objets the following result:

```
DOMAIN(0025D260):HANDLE(Pinned):1f13ec:Root:  02393250(System.Object[]) - from !gcroot
ESP:16f2e4: sizeof(02393250) =    123436600 (   0x75b7e38) bytes (System.Object[]) - size of the pinned arrays of objects
```

System: [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2 32 bit 
Total commited bytes: ~950 MB 
Total reserved bytes: ~ 1,666 MB (numbers are taken from Performance monitor)

The index searcher and therefore the associated index reader is closed regularly after a short batch is done. After that, a new batch is scheduled and works continues. OOM does appear after a couple hours of running. Also the exception is caught, and the service continues to run.

Comment: The Lucene cache (the FieldCache) uses weak references based on open segment readers. The cache entries will not be garbage collected until their respective segment readers are closed.

Comment: @Simon Svensson - Reader is closed after each batch which is quite short (4-5 hundreds of searches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There wasn't a leak, but because of high CPU and memory load the GC threw catcheable System.OutOfMemoryException (OOM) exceptions. So from one side the process continued working and from the other side the index wasn't updated.

At least I managed to somehow lower the pressure on memory and now the system is working OK.

As **Simon Svensson** pointed out, the GC is not collecting if readers are still open, so I decided to check how code is dealing with readers. It turned out that there were a relatively high number of unnecessary places where index was open. Opening the index in one place and sending it as a parameter, made the problem go away.